# Getting an error while concatenating more than two strings using strcat()

Tags: segmentation-fault

I'm trying to concatenate a number of strings stored in an array to an already existing string using strcat() using for loop. It throws Segmentation fault (core dumped). What to do?

Are there any other ways to do it so?

Here's my code...

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    string delimiters[] = {",", "."};
    string name = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        strcat(name, delimiters[i]);
    }

}
```

Error: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

> `string delimiters[] = ...`

I really wish `cs50.h` didn't do that. Using `typedef char *string;` is *nothing but trouble*.

> `string name = "";`
> `strcat(name, ...);`

The `name` points to a *read-only* string literal `""`.

You are trying to copy characters into that read-only memory, which *naturally* leads to `SIGSEGV`.

You need *writable* memory to write characters to. One way to get such writeable memory is:

```
char name[100];
```

P.S. `for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)` makes no sense -- the body of the loop executes *once*, so you may delete the `for` loop and nothing will change.